# is it possible to use Postgres and Oracle in the same project?

Tags: java, oracle, postgresql

I have a java application with Oracle database.
I want to add postgres database for some customers that use **postgres** and not **Oracle**.
How can i use both of them (Oracle and Postgres)?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Define an interface, e.g. `DatabaseStorage`, which specifies methods that would do all of your database interactions. For instance, `public void newCustomer(/* params */);`. Then define `DBOracle` and `DBPostgres`, both of them implementing your super/parent interface and implement how the code is run for each one, satisfying those calls. Then you just use the relevant class based on configuration when starting the program / updating configurations / etc.

Comment: basically yes, it's like you use any other multiple classes in your java project, but overhead of code and integration between them going to be very painfully! suggest a read about spring-boot-jpa https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

Comment: Using standard compliant SQL helps.

Comment: What specific problems are you having with doing so? You can just create a new connection object for the Postgres database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ORM (object-relational mapping) libraries like [Hibernate](https://hibernate.org) are often used to abstract away the implementation details of the application database. Hibernate is quite heavyweight and not easy to insert into an existing project, but there are other, more lightweight alternatives that enable you to read and write data from and to the database without using native SQL commands. They all introduce additional overhead, both in terms of application structure and during runtime - not to mention an additional dependency. Most of them require you to define classes representing your data model in a certain way, and usually you also have to annotate them to tell the ORM which tables and field names to map. During runtime they need to construct the SQL for the database type you use, so they will likely also be a bit slower than native database connections alone (although the impact can vary a lot, that depends on your data model). The advantage is, apart from not having to write the queries, (mostly) database independent development. Depending on the ORM you choose you may be able to use not just Oracle and Postgres, but also Microsoft SQL, MySQL/MariaDb, even sqlite and other popular databases as well.

Whether an ORM is the right choice for your project depends on your requirements, your application structure and the priority of this particular requirement. You may be better served with a smaller solution that only deals with the differences between those particular two databases, moving to an ORM late in a projects life can be rather difficult.

Answer (score 0):

**yes it is possible**

There are many ways to do that:

1. Define an interface, e.g. DatabaseStorage, which specifies methods that would do all of your database interactions.
2. Use jdbc connections more than one. One is to **oracle** other one is **postgres**